# Node.js display variable as HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on trying to display a Node.js variable as HTML.

I currently have this in my app.js which uses Express.

**Package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.4",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "express": "~4.12.2",
    "ejs": "~2.1.3",
    "hbs": "~2.9.0",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.0"
  }
```

**App.js**

```
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

app.post('/calc', function(req, res) {
  res.render('calc', {
  title: 'Calc'});
  var v3 = (req.body.value1 * req.body.value2);
  console.log(v3);
});
```

Within handlebars, I'm just simply seeing if I can see the value rendered, but I'm not able to.

**calc.hbs**
`<h2><%= v3 %></h2>` and `{{v3}}` displays nothing.

What am I missing?

**WORKING SNIPPET**

```
app.post('/calc', function(req, res) {
  var v3 = (req.body.value1 * req.body.value2);
  res.render('calc', {
  title: 'Calc',
  v3: v3});  //Pass the local variables into objects to render
  console.log(v3);
});
```

Comment: That doesn't look like handlebars, it appears to be EJS. Handlebars uses mustache templating like `{{v3}}`

Comment: I updated my question.  I tried that earlier and it didn't render anything.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Are all your template dependencies handled? Also, it may not be your issue,but handlebar's CI is failing currently https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars

Comment: I'm currently developing in Webstorm 10 and NPM is not failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a significant number of problems and really need to go read the [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render). It's not possible to fully deduce your problem without more code (specifically, how you're setting up your view engine), but we can at least identify the problems in the code you posted.

First off, and most importantly, `res.render`'s second argument is a "locals" object, which defines the variables that you can use in your template. **You're not passing the `v3` variable into that object, so your template cannot output it.**

Secondly, you've set up a `POST` route. If you're just visiting `/calc` in your browser, this route will never execute because visiting a page is a `GET` request. It does look like you intend to `POST` since you're using `req.body`, but it's worth mentioning in case you copied this code from somewhere else.

Third, you've passed a template name to `res.render` that has no extension. That means that you **must** specify a default `view engine` for Express to use to load this template. You haven't showed this part of your code, so instead, look at the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.set) to set `view engine`. By default, Express looks in a directory called `views` for the template, so make sure your template is at `/views/calc.hbs` and your `view engine` is set up to be Handlebars (requires setting `view engine` and calling `app.engine` to register Handlebars).

Fourth, you're trying to `console.log` the `v3` variable, which doesn't write to the `res` object, which is the response that will be sent to the browser.

Solving these issues should get you on your way.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I am purposely using `POST` because I'm calculating two variables on the index route.  I've added additional app.js.  If you want to view it again.

Comment: From the code you added, it looks like items 2 and 3 above are OK. So if you pass the `v3` variable as part of the locals object, you should see some output from `{{v3}}`.

Comment: I did that and that works.  Take a look at my edit, and again, thanks for the help.